# facebook audience pixel code crash

Tags: facebook

I put my pixel code beetween

here's the code

```
<!-- Custom Audience Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '111XXXXXXXXXX4518');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<!-- Insert Your Custom Audience Pixel ID below. -->
<noscript>
    <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=111XXXXXXXXXX44518&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Custom Audience Pixel Code -->
```

then I got this error: [image]

I just copy paste the FB code.

thanks

Comment: which browser and version are you using?

Comment: firefox 45.0 on linux mint but it's the same on Chrome

Comment: have you tried in other browser?, your pixel code looks good to me, i don see that semicolon after the function declaration, it looks like an issue you could file on facebook